# Getting marker details when marker is clicked

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

Hello i have this app that could detect users locations. In 1 activity I am displaying all the markers from mysql server using volley lirary and store in an array.

Now I want to get the data esp. the title of the marker and pass it to a String or a textview when it is clicked do something

here is my code:

```
         handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do something after 20 seconds
                if(locationsMarker != null){
                    locationsMarker.remove();
                }

                StringRequest stringRequest2 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, locs_url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                try {
                                    JSONArray array= new JSONArray(response);
                                    JSONObject locations;

                                    String from_lat_lng="";
                                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                        locations = new JSONObject(array.get(i).toString());

                                        String locs = locations.getString("current_loc");

                                        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)").matcher(locs);
                                        while(m.find()) {
                                            from_lat_lng = m.group(1) ;

                                        }

                                        String[] gpsVal = from_lat_lng.split(",");
                                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(gpsVal[0]);
                                        double lon = Double.parseDouble(gpsVal[1]);
                                        LatLng location_array = new LatLng(lat,lon);
                                        Toast.makeText(ScanToHelp.this, "haha="+location_array.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        points.add(location_array); //added
                                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                                        markerOptions.position(location_array);
                                        markerOptions.title("Current Location");
                                        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                                        locationsMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
//                                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location_array));
//                                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location_array, 17.2f));



                                    }


                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

                MySingleton.getInstance(ScanToHelp.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest2);


                handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            }
        }, 100);  //the time is in miliseconds
```

Thanks,